# PWA - Como usar o evento beforeinstallprompt?

Tags: javascript, pwa, progressive-web-apps

Tenho um Progressive Web Apps e estou tentando criar uma função para saber quantos usuários "instalam" ou não meu app.
De acordo com a documentação (https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6560913322672128) eu adicionei o seguinte código abaixo da função que chama o Service Worker.js:

```js
 window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
   // beforeinstallprompt Event fired

   // e.userChoice will return a Promise. 
   // For more details read: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises
   e.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {

  console.log(choiceResult.outcome);

  if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed') {
    console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
    $('h1').after('Canceled');
    $.get('https://www.meusite.com/register.php?a=Cancelou');
  }
  else {
    console.log('User added to home screen');
    $('h1').after('Installed');
    $.get('https://www.meusite.com/register.php?a=Instalou');
  }
   });
 });
```

A ideia é que após adicionar a home screen ou cancelar, iria aparecer logo em baixo do título (h1) da página, e avisar o servidor através do $.get no arquivo register.php que salva num TXT a data/hora seguido de Instalou ou Cancelou.

Bom ai que está a questão, que mesmo adicionando ou não à home screen não aparece o aviso em baixo do titulo nem o PHP recebe a informação...

Para testar também estou apanhando um pouco, a função que tem nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chorme de Adicionar a Home Screen parece que não funciona mais a algumas versões, quando clico nada acontece (apenas da um retorno no colsole sobre o Service Worker).

Alguém tem experiência com isso pode me dar uma orientação?

grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver.

O uso da função está correto, o que ocorre é que somente "entra" nesta função quando a instalação é efetuada quando surge a popup no navegador perguntando se o usuário deseja adicionar à Home Screen (se o usuário for no Menu do Chrome e mandar adicionar a home, esta função não é executada).

E também eu não estava recebendo os retornos do $.get() pois depende o jQuery que era chamado no início do index.html mas não sei porque não funcionou, então fiz uma função similar com Javascript puro:

```js
//Função equivalente ao $.get do jQuery
function get(url){
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', url);
 xhr.send();
}

//Registra a instalação nos Logs
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
  // beforeinstallprompt Event fired

  // e.userChoice will return a Promise. 
  // For more details read: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises
  e.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {

 console.log(choiceResult.outcome);

 if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed') {
   console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
   $('h1').after('Canceled');
   get('https://www.meusite.com/register.php?a=Cancelou');
 }
 else {
   console.log('User added to home screen');
   $('h1').after('Installed');
   get('https://www.meusite.com/register.php?a=Instalou');
 }
  });
});
```

Comment: Você adicionou o evento beforeinstallprompt dentro do sw.js ?